# useState with react giving me issues with onChange handler for google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting a state variable with useState whether or not a recaptcha has been clicked, but when I use the setState function my captcha variable doesn't pass ot my on submit, don't understand why, If I remove the setState the captcha variable passes just fine to my onSubmit.
If I remove setSubmitButton(false) everything works fine, not quite sure why.

When I run the setSubmittButton(false) captcha is endefined in my submit function when I dont have it there I get the correct captcha value in my submit function.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha"

const ContactForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm()

  const isBrowser = typeof window !== `undefined`
  let location
  if (isBrowser) {
    location = window.location.hostname
  }
  let fetchUrl
  if (location === "localhost") {
    fetchUrl = `http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/contact`
  } else if (location === "fsdf.gtsb.io") {
    fetchUrl = `https://fdsfd/.netlify/functions/contact`
  } else {
    fetchUrl = "/.netlify/functions/contact"
  }

  console.log(fetchUrl)

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    setLoading(true)
    console.log(captcha, "captcha value final")
    const response = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ data, captcha: captcha }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.captcha === false) {
          setCaptchaFailed(true)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error)
      })
  }
  const [submitButton, setSubmitButton] = useState(true)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [captchaFailed, setCaptchaFailed] = useState(false)

  let captcha

  function onChange(value) {
    setSubmitButton(false) // IF I REMOVE THIS LINE EVERYTHING WORKS FINE ******
    console.log("Captcha value:", value)
    captcha = value
  }

  function error(value) {
    alert(value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */}
      {!loading ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input name="name" ref={register({ required: true })} />
            {errors.name && <span>This field is required</span>}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              ref={register({ required: true })}
            />
            {errors.email && <span>This field is required</span>}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" ref={register({ required: true })} />
            {errors.message && <span>This field is required</span>}
          </div>
          <ReCAPTCHA
            sitekey="fdsfsa"
            onChange={onChange}
            onErrored={error}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            className={submitButton ? "disabled" : ""}
            disabled={submitButton ? "disabled" : ""}
          />
        </form>
      ) : (
        <>
          {captchaFailed ? (
            <>
              <p>Captcha Verification Failed</p>
            </>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading</h1>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

Comment: At first glance, I think that since captcha is a simple variable and not a state variable, when the setSubmitButton gets executed, the Component re-renders and resets the captcha variable to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the captcha value in a state variable (or ref) instead of a plain JS variable. The plain JS variable will reset to `undefined` when the component re-renders (after the `setSubmitButton` changes the state).

```
const [ captchaValue, setCaptchaValue ] = useState(null);

function onChange(value) {
    setSubmitButton(false); 
    console.log("Captcha value:", value);
    setCaptchaValue(value);
}

const onSubmit = async data => {
    setLoading(true)
    console.log(captchaValue, "captcha value final");
    ...
}
```

---

**Tip:** Also, make sure to replace all the occurrences of the `for` html attributes to `htmlFor`. You can use an [HTML-to-JSX transformer](https://transform.tools/html-to-jsx) for automating such tasks.

Comment: Aha makes sense. Thanks